# lazy with internal reference

Tags: swift, instance, lazy-evaluation

In Swift 3.0 I like to use a struct which is filled, only when needed. 
So I have :

```
class Classname : NSObject, NSCopying, Comparable { ...

    lazy var exif : EXIFData = {
        return EXIFData(url: globalURL as CFURL)
    }()
```

If I use an external var as parameter for EXIFData() "globalURL", it compiles.
 If I use an instance member, compiler tells me, that it cannot be used on that class type. 
What did I worng and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got it. I only need self. in front of instance member.